# adding dynamically a property to a class in HTML

Tags: html, css, django

I've got these css classes:

```
planning a span.icon {
    background-image:url(../img/icon1.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

.planning a:hover span.icon {
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

In my template, I want to loop on an item (blurb) and dynamically update the value for the property `background-image`.

For now, I've tried to remove `background-image` from css class and added it in the template without success:

```
{% for blurb in page.homepage.blurbs.all %}
    <div class="span4">
    <a href={{ blurb.link }}>
    <span class="img_icon icon" style="background-image: {% static blurb.icon %}"></span>
       </a>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It ends up that the background-image property isn't attributed to the class icon.

Any idea to do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `url()` around the image URL.

```
<span class="img_icon icon" style="background-image: url({% static blurb.icon %})"></span>
```

should work (if `blurb.icon` is a URL of course, if it is a `ImageField` value, you must use `blurb.icon.url`).